# How to prevent Worksheet_Change Event from running when adding or deleting rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total novice when it comes to programming.  I'm working on a spreadsheet to capture training information.  The code listed below inputs the username (from a module the defines username as the Window username), date and time.  My problem is, when rows are added or deleted, it causes the the sub to run.  What can I do to prevent that? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Rng = Range("D11:D88")
If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Target(1).Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ$("username")
  Target(1).Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
  Target(1).Offset(0, 3).Value = Time
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Rng = Range("D11:D88")
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
          Application.EnableEvents = False
          Target(1).Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ$("username")
          Target(1).Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
          Target(1).Offset(0, 3).Value = Time
          Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```